# Compare date in two year

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have a table of population that I want to compare population in two year.

My table structure:
id (auto increment), type (man,woman,child), population (1 to 10000), date

I want run two under query and show into one table result:

query1:

```
SELECT type,count(population) as count_of_year1
FROM population
where date between '2013-01-01' and '2013-01-24'
GROUP BY type
```

query2:

```
SELECT type, count(population) as count_of_year2
FROM population
where date between '2014-01-01' and '2014-01-24'
GROUP BY type
```

I need this result :

|    Type    |  population in year2013| population in year 2014

How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `case` expressions to do conditional counting:

```
SELECT type,
       count(case when date between '2013-01-01' and '2013-01-24' then population end) as count_of_year1,
       count(case when date between '2014-01-01' and '2014-01-24' then population end) as count_of_year2
FROM population
GROUP BY type
```

Add this `where` clause to speed things up if needed:

```
where date between '2013-01-01' and '2013-01-24'
   or date between '2014-01-01' and '2014-01-24'
```

Comment: tank you. I  want add column to show sum of population in year 2013.this possible? how to add this condition inside case expressions

Comment: Now when I read your question again I'm not quite sure I've answered it... May come back with an adjusted query later! Or is this what you're asking for?

Answer (score 0):

As population can have a value from 1 to 10000, I assume you want SUM() here not COUNT().

I'd have a separate table for types:

- population_type - id, title
- population - id, type_id (references type.id), population, date

Then I prefer using JOINs here:

```
    SELECT pt.title type,
           COALESCE(y1.total_population,0) population_2013,
           COALESCE(y2.total_population,0) population_2014
      FROM population_type pt
 LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT type_id,
               SUM(population) total_population,
          FROM population
         WHERE date >= '2013-01-01'
           AND date < '2013-01-24' + INTERVAL 1 DAY           
      GROUP BY type
           ) y1
        ON y1.type_id = pt.id          
 LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT type_id,
               SUM(population) total_population,
          FROM population
         WHERE date >= '2014-01-01'
           AND date < '2014-01-24' + INTERVAL 1 DAY           
      GROUP BY type
           ) y2
        ON y2.type_id = pt.id
```

This way you are only summing through what you need each time and the query is more modular.